# Como fazer login com php e session no ionic?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic

Estou a fazer uma aplicação móvel com `ionic` e tenho de fazer um login de utilizadores de uma base de dados externa, preciso de saber como posso fazer o login atraves do php e criar um sessao com o `id` do utilizador ?

Answer (score 2):

Faça com **Token** cara, já experimentei com session, cookies , mas token é o mais recomendado, mantendo o status logado do app, se é isso que tabm deseja deseja;

Use esse link com apoio:
[Autencticação IONIC / TOKEN /AngularJS](http://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/)

Answer (score 0):

Como o @Vagner disse token é o mais recomendado. Porém se você quiser um exemplo com session talvez isso possa ajudar:

```
//Atribui o objeto usuário a referencia usuarioLogado no sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('usuarioLogado', usuario);
```

Depois se voce quiser recuperar esse usuário voce pode fazer:

```
/**Pega o objeto armazenado no sessionStorage, 
observe que a referencia é a mesma('usuarioLogado')*/
$scope.usuarioLogado = sessionStorage.getItem('usuarioLogado');
```